# Why might one single key:value pair be undefined in an object while others are accessible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm currently getting more familiar with Node.js and I'm building out a restful API. I have a config file where I store things like the environment name (staging v prod), the port number to run my server on and a hashing secret (using sha256 to hash a user pwd).

Everything is defined except for the hashing secret (it's the last key:value entry in my object). Logging out other values works just fine - trying to log out the hashing secret just says undefined. I've been going crazy for the last 2 hours here.

#### config.js

```js
var environments = {}
environments.staging = {
  'httpPort': 3000,
  'httpsPort': 3001,
  'envName': 'staging',
  'hashingSecret': 'thisIsASecret'
};

environments.production = {
  'httpPort': 5000,
  'httpsPort': 5001,
  'envName': 'production',
  'hashingSecret': 'thisIsAlsoASecret'
};
var passedEnvironment = typeof(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'string' ? process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() : ''
// check that passed in NODE_ENV value exists in our config container object
var configEnvironment = environments.hasOwnProperty(passedEnvironment) ? environments[passedEnvironment] : environments.staging
module.exports = configEnvironment
```

and then my file where I have helper functions (such as a function to hash a user pwd) looks like this:

```js
// Dependencies
var crypto = require('crypto')
var config = require('./config')
// Container for our helper functions
var helpers = {}
// Define helper functions
helpers.hash = function(str) {
  // validate our string input
  if (typeof(str) == 'string' && str.length > 0) {
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.hashingSecret).update(str).digest('hex')
    return hash
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

I'm constantly seeing

> TypeError: Key must be a buffer

referring to the `config.hashingSecret` OR, if I try to log out the hashing secret BEFORE using it to create a hash, I get 'undefined'.

I'm going absolutely crazy - particularly because all of the other object properties ARE defined. To me that means that the module is exporting correctly and the object is initialized.

Using typeof tells me that config is an object - not sure where to go from here.

UPDATE -

I figured out the solution to my issue - I was requiring an old (cached) version of my config module. I had changed the project directory structure and neglected to update all of my require statements - I was making changes to the config file in the new location but the project was continuing to use the cached file from the old location. As a result, any changes made to the file weren't being served to the project (even though they'd appear in code as I typed them out in VSCode).

Comment: I just pasted both code snippets into a project and logged out `config.hashingSecret` and it works fine here - Am I missing something with too simple a repro? I've also tried invoking your `helpers.hash` function with different values and it also works.

Comment: try to destructure the `hashingSecret` property. am on mobile now, so i can't try anything

Comment: have u seen the documentation of `crypto.createHmac` ??

Comment: I agree with @KirkLarkin and your initial assumption: There is something wrong with config.js or the importing of that file. Some things to check are variable spelling mistakes or path resolution. Or maybe you tried to give us a minimal example and removed too much? Here is a working example that is almost exactly the same as what you shared: https://runkit.com/mitchlillie/import-and-export

Comment: @MitchLillie @KirkLarkin the strange thing is that if I try and replace `config.hashingSecret` with `config.envName`, I get no undefined error.

Comment: You need to try and include a [mcve] of the problem. As it currently stands, there’s not enough information here for a solution to be suggested.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I'll go back to the drawing board and edit the question. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It’s an interesting issue but I think we’re stuck right now. Good luck.